# proto c++ implementation - "marked ‘override’, but does not override" error

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

```
// api_internal.proto
service InvoiceTemplateMatcher {
   rpc Process(InvoiceFilePath) returns (UploadStatus) {}
}

message InvoiceFilePath {
   string invoice_id = 1;
   string file_path = 2;
}

// template_matcher/src/main.cc
class OrkaEngineInvoiceTemplateMatcherImpl final : public InvoiceTemplateMatcher::Service {
private:
    Status Process(
        ServerContext* context,
        orka_engine_internal::InvoiceFilePath* invoicefp,
        orka_engine_internal::UploadStatus* response) override {
    // do stuff
    }
};
```

Class `InvoiceTemplateMatcher::Service` is generated during compile time from that `.proto` file.

When I try to compile, I get an error

```
‘grpc::Status OrkaEngineInvoiceTemplateMatcherImpl::Process(grpc::ServerContext*, orka_engine_internal::InvoiceFilePath*, orka_engine_internal::UploadStatus*)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
     Status Process(ServerContext* context, orka_engine_internal::InvoiceFilePath* invoicefp, orka_engine_internal::UploadStatus* response) override {
```

As far as I can tell, my code is written in the same way as in [Route Guide example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.19.0/examples/cpp/route_guide). What am I missing?

Comment: what is `InvoiceTemplateMatcher::Service` ? does it really have a `orka_engine_internal::UploadStatus* response)` ?

Comment: That class is automatically generated by protoc, that is called by cmake. It should have that as until I messed with service description, everything worked, but I don't see it on my filesystem.

Comment: even if autogenerated you can look at the generated code, no?

Comment: I don't see it. find / -name "orka_engine_internal.grpc.pb.h" found nothing. I lacked plugins to manually generate the base classes to inspect them, off to try that now.

Answer (score 16):

Such an error is issued by the compiler when the the function is not marked `virtual` in the base class.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
class Base{
    void Foo() {}
};

class Derived : Base{
    void Foo() override {}
};
```

Compiler issues the error:

```
error: 'void Derived::Foo()' marked 'override', but does not override
     void Foo() override {}
```

See **[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cTP-uH)**

The [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier specifies that a `virtual` function overrides another `virtual` function.

Comment: Here, base class is automatically generated during compilation from .proto file; I don't really have a control over that. Could it also be a signature mismatch?

Comment: What about derived class? Is it also generated?

Comment: No, the OrkaEngineInvoiceTemplateMatcherImpl is what I write.

Comment: Just to register another reason for this error, my function was marked as virtual in the base class, but the **signature** of that function in the derived class was not the same as in the base class. That was not easy to perceive because of many typedefs in the derived class.

Answer (score 5):

I know that this post is quite old but I will give a correct answer for any future troubleshoots that person might across while wokring with protobufs.

You are correct saying that the class implementation has been generated automatically and protobuf c++ generation has this class function by default:

```
virtual ::grpc::Status Process(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const ::orka_engine_internal::InvoiceFilePath* request, ::orka_engine_internal::UploadStatus* response);
```

So you need to match your function exactly to virtual function. In your example, just change `invoicefp` to `request`